# RoR: a has_one and has_many reference in same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

Say I have a model called Device, and another model called Firmware (which contains a firmware version number and other info). I would like to keep track of the history of firmware versions installed on the device, but also a reference to the current version (which may or may not be the most recent date-wise).

How do I set up my associations so that I can point to one specific firmware configuration (the current one) and also several different firmware configurations (the history)?

Answer (score 9):

Add `device_current_id` integer column to the firmwares table and then:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :current_firmware, class_name: "Firmware", foreign_key: "device_current_id"
  has_many :firmwares
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:class_name` in you associations like...

Device Model

```
has_one :current_firmware, class_name :firmware
has_many :old_firmwares, class_name :firmware
```

Comment: You'll also need to add a foreign key to your firmwares table.

Comment: Not sure if that is what meagar meant but this is not correct. current_firmware would just return the first firmware with the given device_id in no specific order. Also as far as I know you can't use a symbol for the class_name key's value.